# HLS Steaming in WIndows 8

Tags: windows, http-live-streaming

I am trying to use the hls framework (https://phonesm.codeplex.com/) on Windows 8.0. i have converted HLSView project to Windows 8.0. But Visual Studio tells me that

static readonly IApplicationInformation ApplicationInformation = ApplicationInformationFactory.DefaultTask.Result; does not exist in current context

_mediaStreamFascade = MediaStreamFascadeSettings.Parameters.Create(_httpClients, _mediaElementManager.SetSourceAsync); does not contain a definition for "create"

```
 _mediaElementManager = new WinRtMediaElementManager(Dispatcher, WinRtMediaElementManager could not be found.
```

I need to integrate this in a Windows 8.0 project. I have read that it is possible, but i don't know how to get past those errors

I have just tried 72bb1b6bb7f3 version (last commit). i have converted hlsview.win81 project to a windows 8.0 project. After commenting SystemMediaTransportControls i only had 2 problems:

Error 7 The base class or interface of 'SM.Media.IMediaStreamFacade' could not be resolved or is invalid c:\Users\Sergiu\Downloads\phonesm-72bb1b6bb7f3885c65e157823b7cf2d341fa5c95\Source\bin\Debug\SM.Media.Platform.WinRT.dll HlsView.Win81

and at mediaElement1.SetMediaStreamSource(mss);

Error 21 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.MediaElement' does not contain a definition for 'SetMediaStreamSource' and no extension method 'SetMediaStreamSource' accepting a first argument of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.MediaElement' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) c:\users\sergiu\downloads\phonesm-72bb1b6bb7f3885c65e157823b7cf2d341fa5c95\source\app\winrt\hlsview.win81\mainpage.xaml.cs 348 39 HlsView.Win81

I don't know how to make it work from here for windows 8.0. Please any help is welcomed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

henric (the phonesm creator) answered this question in https://phonesm.codeplex.com/discussions/569208

Basically you have to implement mediastreamsource yourself for windows 8.